# Data retrieval Issue

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

I haven't found a common sense way to retrieve a value from a column that has a space in it. For example Medal of Honor would be the column name and the value would be a number 0-15. yet the moment i write

```
if($Medal of Honor >= 1) {
```

the $Medal is read as the value and not $Medal of Honor Duh right

I tried to add [] {} '' "" as possible around the variable with no success

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) so that column names with white space will keep as array keys.
You may access them like `$row['Medal of Honor']` .

Comment: thank you that's the solution that has been evading me for the past 2 hours.